# Application.runInBackground is true by default

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-engine

According to Unity docs https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-runInBackground.html the default value of Application.runInBackground bool is false. But in my case it is showing true by default.

I have checked by creating a new project on unity version 2018.1.3 & 2018.4.12.

```
public class temp : MonoBehaviour 
{

 void Start () 
 {
    print("Run in bg Status(Application) : "+Application.runInBackground);
 }

}
```

I  know i can set it to false but want to know if i am doing something wrong.

Comment: Considering your tags, this is for Android ?

Answer (score 0):

If it's set to set to true in a new project than that is probably the case. It is possible you might be able to change this somewhere in the project's settings instead of doing it in code somewhere else but I'm not sure about that.

In my experience the unity documentation is poorly maintained and very slow to be updated, it used to be good a few years ago but their update frequency has increased a lot since then. I take everything that I read on there with a grain of salt.

Comment: Thank you for responding.

I have created an empty project and double checked all the settings.
And i agree with you on unity docs.